# using Java switch statement return null but not the expected outcome

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
public class Phone {
   private  String Band;
   double price;
   String Category;

void setPrice(double newPrice)
{
price = newPrice;
}
double getPrice(){
return price;
}
void setBand(String newBand)
{
Band = newBand;
}
String getBand(){
return Band;
}
void setCategory(String newCategory){
Category = newCategory;
}
String getCategory()
{
return Category;
}
public String Category(double price){
switch(price){
case 1: 
if (price>=8000){
Category= "Expensive";
break;
}
case 2:
if(price>=5000 && size<7000){
Category = "Normal";
break;
}
default:
Category = "Cheap";
}
return Category;
}
}
public class TestPhone{
public static void main (String[]args){    
Phone PhoneN = new Phone();
PhoneN.setPrice=6500;
System.out.println(PhoneA.getCategory());
}
}
```

However, the result is null. (when I run the TestPhone class)
Actually , it should be "Normal".
What did I set wrongly in the code?
I just try to use the getter and setter method, and try to apply in the Category also.
Or is it Is this the problem of the data type of price?
Is this the problem of operator?
What's the problem?
Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry , should be  System.out.println(PhoneN.getCategory());

Comment: Please [edit] the question and format the code properly.

Comment: What's the point of using `switch` and inside `if` ? you can only use `if else` statements and do this one

Comment: @user14917213 Your test code never sets a value for the PhoneN's Category, so it is null.

Comment: I think the switch statement is used wrongly over here. You are supposed to enter the condition to match after case. example ```switch(rank){case "newbie": System.out.println("you are a newbie"); break; case "super man": System.out.println("you are a superman"); break;}```

Comment: what is: `(price>=5000 && size<7000)`? Shouldn't that be: `(price>=5000 && price<8000)`? Where does `size` come from?

Answer (score 1):

**Please learn how `switch` statement works. You can learn from here: [Switch in Java](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp)**

You're passing `price` in `switch(price)` but comparing with `1, 2, 3,`etc. **Here is the problem.**

`switch-case` are always denotes equal. Your program is working like:

```java
if(price == 1) { 
    if (price>=8000){
    Category= "Expensive";
} else if(price == 2) {
    if(price>=5000 && size<7000){
    Category = "Normal";
} else {
    Category = "Cheap";
}
```

`switch` is can't be used in this case. Use `if else` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code.

- It doesn't compile because you cannot have a `switch` statement over `double` values - the value must be either char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum - you can fix this by declaring the method as `public String Category(int price) {}`
- Then the switch statement tries to use an undefined symbol `size` - probably you meant to use `price` there?
- In the main method you write `PhoneN.setPrice=6500;`, but the `Phone` class has no field `setPrice` - you probably wanted to write `PhoneN.setPrice(6500);`
- the next line is `System.out.println(PhoneA.getCategory());` - here again, the symbol `PhoneA` is never declared, you probably meant `System.out.println(PhoneN.getCategory());`

Fixing all these points you still have the problem that @philoopher97 mentions in his answer: in the `switch-case` the statements after `case 1:` are executed when `price` is 1, which means that the condition `price >= 8000` cannot be fulfilled, similar for `case 2:`

This leads to the last problem: your code never calls the `setCategory()` or the `Category()` method and that means that the `Category` field of the `PhoneN` object is never set to anything but `null`.